# python sklearn decision tree classifier feature_importances_ with feature names when using continuous values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, data-science

I'm using sklearn Decision Tree Classifier with some continuous features.
When I run export_graphviz I see the same features in more than one nodes and with different values. Example:
[image]

I would like to take the top important ones and want to use feature_importances_ for that.
The problem is that feature_importances_ is array without reference to the tree nodes. I have the original features but as each one can be more than one time in the tree I'm not sure how to relate importance to node.

Comment: Moved the question to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26013/python-sklearn-decision-tree-classifier-feature-importances-with-feature-names